# How to debug Gobblin standalone?

Tags: gobblin

How to run Gobblin in debug mode from IntelliJ IDE using bin/gobblin-standalone.sh command?

[Getting started tutorial](https://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-Started/) suggests how to run sample Gobblin job, but it is unclear how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start remote debugger in IntelliJ, and then configure Gobblin JVM to connect to it.

In IntelliJ, add a "Remote" debug configuration. Make sure to set the "Debugger mode" to Listen. 
Check "Auto restart" box, if it's available.

[image: IntelliJ remote debugger]

Set a breakpoint in your code
[image: Breakpoint]

Start the "Remote" debug configuration:

[image: Start remote debug configuration]

Start Gobblin with extra command line option `--jvmopts` :

```
bin/gobblin service standalone start --jvmopts -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=localhost:5005,suspend=n
```

You can also check out [detailed explanation of Java remote debugger settings](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-agentlibjdwp-for-attaching.html).

For up-to-date help about command line arguments, run `bin/gobblin service standalone`